# JQuery Autocomplete doesn't work when replacing a SPAN to an INPUT

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an input field which is using the autocomplete function. When I only do this, the autocomplete works. But: I want to display a span and replace it for an inputbox when a user clicks on it. Unfortunately, the autocomplete function breaks. Considering the following code:

```
$(function () {
    
    $('#my_span').live('click', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'id': 'my_input', 'name': 'my_input', 'value': $(this).html()});
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    }
    
    
    );

    $('#my_input').live('blur', function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />' , {'id': 'my_span'}).html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
    });
});

$("#my_input").autocomplete({
        source: function(req, resp) {
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/grootjeframework/testproject/json/find/partij/naam/" + encodeURIComponent(req.term), resp);
        },

        select: function(event,ui){
             //do Stuff
        }
    });
```

(the editor considers my HTML span as a span element ;) so I can't post it. For your information: its just a normal span with an ID 'my_span')

The replacement of the input and span works fine. The autocomplete, without the replacement scripts, works also fine. But, combining both, the `autocompletefunction` breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'my_input' is created only on 'my_span' click, so when you attach 'blur' event handler on it and autocomplete plugin it doesn't exist yet.

Try doing something like this:

```
$(function () {

    $('#my_span').live('click', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'id': 'my_input', 'name': 'my_input', 'value': $(this).html()});

        input.live('blur', function () {
            $(this).parent().append($('<span />' , {'id': 'my_span'}).html($(this).val()));
            $(this).remove();
        });

        input.autocomplete({
            source: function(req, resp) {
                $.getJSON("http://localhost/grootjeframework/testproject/json/find/partij/naam/" + encodeURIComponent(req.term), resp);
            },

            select: function(event,ui){
                 //do Stuff
            }
        }); 

        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

});
```

This way you attach event handler and autocomplete on element after it's creation.

Comment: I'Am sorry, I couldn't vote your post, because my level is too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leonti I could finisch my task. I edited the solution in the following. From now the  inputbox will change in a span, after clicking an item in the JSON item list.

```
$(function () {

    $('#my_span').live('click', function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'id': 'my_input', 'name': 'my_input', 'value': $(this).html()});

        input.autocomplete({
            source: function(req, resp) {
                $.getJSON("http://localhost/grootjeframework/testproject/json/find/partij/naam/" + encodeURIComponent(req.term), resp);
            },

            select: function(event,ui){
                $("#id_partij_samengevoegd").attr("value", ui.item.id );
                $('#my_span').remove();
                input.parent().append($('<span />' , {'id': 'my_span'}).html(ui.item.value));
                input.remove();
            }
        });    

        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
    });

});
```